# Visual Studio icons by version

Tags: c#

I have solutions created with different Visual Studio versions, from 2005 to 2019. I want to get the proper .sln icon for each one of it.

For VS2005: [image: This for VS2005]

For VS2010: [image]

For VS2019: [image]

Is there any way to do this in C#? I'm trying it with `Shell32.Shfileinfo`, but it always returns the same one (VS2005).

Comment: The "Visual Studio Launcher" does the magic to distinguish which version of VS to show as the icon and to launch.  It does this by looking inside the SLN and project files. You aren't going to get a CS file distinguishing between which version of VS it belongs to - there's no difference between CS files.  If you want to change the icon and startup associations, you need to do it in the standard way (in the registry or the UI).  This might help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/registering-verbs-for-file-name-extensions

Comment: Thank you @Flydog57. I was trying to avoid that but seems to be the "almost" only solution for this. We are creating a Project Navigator (sort of), and your proposal is one of the solution, and the other is to dig into the SLN file to get the version and show the proper icon. Let's see where we end with.

Answer (score 0):

We finally decided to go through the laziest and fastest way. It's a draft, but working:

```
  public static Image SolutionIcon(this string pFile)
  {
     string sContent = File.ReadAllText(pFile);

     if (sContent.Contains("Visual Studio 2005"))
     {
        return Properties.Resources.VS2005;
     }
     if (sContent.Contains("Visual C# Express 2008"))
     {
        return Properties.Resources.VS2008Xpress;
     }
     if (sContent.Contains("Visual Studio 2008"))
     {
        return Properties.Resources.VS2008;
     }
     if (sContent.Contains("Visual Studio 2010"))
     {
        return Properties.Resources.VS2010;
     }
     if (sContent.Contains("Visual Studio Express 2013"))
     {
        return Properties.Resources.VS2013;
     }
     if (sContent.Contains("Visual Studio 14"))
     {
        return Properties.Resources.VS2015;
     }
     if (sContent.Contains("Visual Studio 15"))
     {
        return Properties.Resources.VS2017;
     }
     if (sContent.Contains("Visual Studio Version 16"))
     {
        return Properties.Resources.VS2019;
     }

     return Properties.Resources.VSCommon;
  }
```

Where **pFile** is the path to the Visual Studio Solution file (.sln)

Comment: I like your thinking, but you can make this better by just running a `for` loop or creating some kind of array/dictionary. You could eliminate all this down to 5-10 lines and if the file contains a certain version, return the respective resources (in an `object` array or something).

Comment: You are right @CyanCoding. Much better code your way. Thank you!